# Emulate touchscreen on a non-touchscreeen Android device

Tags: android

Our mobile app works great with touchscreen Android devices. I need to support a new device that does not have a touchscreen but has DPad keys. I am thinking I can capture DPad direction keys and emulate a cursor arrow on the screen.

Is mouse cursor functionality built into core Android that can simply be turned on by an API call? Are there methods to get/set cursor location on the screen? Also, when the user presses `Enter` on the DPad key, can I emulate a touchscreen event programmatically? Regards.

Answer (score 0):

> Is mouse cursor functionality built into core Android that can simply be turned on by an API call?

Only if the user is using a mouse, in which case no API call is needed.

> Are there methods to get/set cursor location on the screen?

No.

> Also, when the user presses Enter on the DPad key, can I emulate a touchscreen event programmatically?

No. Nor should you need to. Your app will find out about all key presses via methods like `onKeyDown()`. When you get [`KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER), you just do whatever is needed; there is no need to emulate a touchscreen event, just to route to some `onTouchEvent()` method.

Comment: Thank you for your help. We are using custom buttons and list views. Trying to handle dpad keys for each specific layout, and manage showing/hiding the control under focus, is just a code maintenance headache. I was hoping if I could simply emulate touchscreen behavior, I won't have to write custom code for each layout.

Comment: @Peter: "I was hoping if I could simply emulate touchscreen behavior, I won't have to write custom code for each layout" -- or, find a way to achieve whatever look-and-feel you are seeking by styling existing Android widgets, as `Button` and `ListView` are both navigable by keys (`RecyclerView` isn't quite as "out of the box" on this, but it's manageable).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, please read "Making Apps more Accessible": 
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/apps.html

Key events (such as D-pad controls) come into the app in the form of key events

```
onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
```

Touch events come into the app via

```
onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
```

Android does indeed support a cursor (mouse).  It also has frameworks for managing focus, the highlight that appears around onscreen widgets.

Pressing enter on a D-pad is not synonymous with touching a screen - they are different events and need to be handled accordingly.  The above reference doc will point you in the right direction.